# Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client for Azure Cosmos multiple calls

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I"m trying to understand why the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client makes multiple calls when running a query.

var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxItemCount = 100};

```
                var myobj = cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<myCosmosObj>(documentUri, option)
                    .Where(x => x.ID == request.Id);


                while (myobj.AsDocumentQuery().HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var results = await myobj.AsDocumentQuery().ExecuteNextAsync<myCosmosObj>();

                    resultList.AddRange(results);
                }
```

A Fiddler trace shows 5 calls to the cosmos collection dbs/mycollectionname/colls/docs  (the while loop above runs 5 times)

My question is 1 network hop would improve performance, so I would like to understand why it is making 5 network calls, and If there is something I need to do with the configuration to adjust this.  I have already tried adjusting the ResultSize.  This is roughly a 3GB collection.

Comment: Is your collection fixed-10GB, or partitioned? If partitioned: You enabled cross-partition queries. And you didn't specify a partition key. So, it has to search for that id within every partition.

Comment: There could be something else going on, but without any trace being shown, within your question, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Yes it is partitioned, so I need to specify the partition key in code I guess?

Comment: Correct - see my answer posted below. I also pointed out something about read vs query.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is theoretically correct however it is missing a crucial point.

Your code is wrong. The way your create the document query inside the loop means that you will always query the result of the first execution 5 times.

The code should actually be like this:

```
var query = cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<myCosmosObj>(documentUri, option)
        .Where(x => x.ID == request.Id).AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var results = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<myCosmosObj>();
    resultList.AddRange(results);
}
```

This will now properly run your query and it will use the continuation properties of the query object in order to read the next page in `ExecuteNextAsync`.

Comment: This still does 5 calls, making the AsDocumentQuery line above the while clause is no different.

Comment: Is the loop doing the 5 calls though? I would expect it to be the SDK itself.

Comment: I believe the SDK is doing the calls as it is coming from query.HasMoreResults

Answer (score 1):

With a partitioned collection, the most efficient way to find a document by id is by also specifying the partition key (which then directs your query to a single partition). Without PK, there's really no way to know, up front, which partition your documents will reside in. And that's likely why you're seeing 5 calls (you likely have 5 partitions).

The alternative, which your code shows, is to do a cross-partition query, which has to do one query per partition, to seek the document you're looking for.

One more thing to note: A *query* will have higher RU cost than a *Read*. And if you already know the partition key and id, there's no need to invoke the query engine (as you can only retrieve a single document anyway, for a given partition key + row key combination).

Comment: The `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` will just add the header for the request to CosmosDB. It's an instruction that tell the engine internally to search in all partitions. It shouldn't lead to multiple calls. The work for that should be done in the server side. Changing the `MaxItemCount` to -1 would actually prove that.

Comment: var option = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxItemCount = -1}; still made 5 calls.

Comment: @David are you referring to read as in this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.readdocumentasync)  I have an Custom ID property on my document, and I"m using that as the partition key, it looks like this call is referring to the id as it is assigned by Cosmos, i wouldn't know that value in my app.

Comment: @cjsmith411 - yes. I didn't realize you were using a different id property.